# debug erlang application with emacs and distel

Tags: erlang

I don't want to reinvent the wheel ...
I am looking for how to configure emacs with distel in order to debug erlang application.
I am on windows 2003 server.
.emacs file must be modified but what else ? does a simple procedure exist ?

Answer (score 0):

http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070528.html

I think I've only set it up on linux and mac, though. Hopefully there's not too many (or any!) gotchas.

Comment: I know this blog. Doesn't work for me ? I always have the following message: Module is not interpreted ...

Comment: It seems that an .erlang file must contain a path to distel. I didn' find any file with this name in my computer ! and under windows the files cannot begin by a dot. Shall I create this file and how ?

Comment: I don't have time to try it, but perhaps these clues will help. You can create files in Windows that start with a dot if you install the cygwin unix environment. You can find the directory that erlang thinks is "home" (where the .erlang file should go) by calling the right module function. I forget what it is, but Joe mentions it in his book, I think when discussing the .cookie file.